# Using a floatrow environment outside a figure environment

Tags: floats, floatrow

I use the `floatrow` package to manage my figures. Sometimes one cannot put figures inside a `figure` environment (e.g. inside a `mdframed` environment). Hopefully, the `\ffigbox` macro works outside the `figure` environment but it is no more the case when I use it inside a `floatrow` environment.

Is there a way to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\ffigbox{Test}{\caption{Test}}
\end{figure}

% Works!
\ffigbox{Test}{\caption{Test}}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{Test}{\caption{Test}}
\ffigbox{Test}{\caption{Test}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

% This won't work.
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{Test}{\caption{Test}}
\ffigbox{Test}{\caption{Test}}
\end{floatrow}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that doing a simple `\def\@captype{figure}` before the `floatrow` environment does the job. But I'd like to be sure it has no side effect.

Comment: The `\ffigbox` is not the issue here: the `floatrow` environment 'expects' to be inside a float (try just a blank environment on its own). That said, I think you approach of simply forcing the caption type is the answer: that's more or less what `\captof` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `floatrow` environment is designed to be used within a float: it relies on `\@captype` begin defined. As such, the error is nothing to do with `\ffgigbox`. Thus the approach of setting `\@captype` is probably the best plan here.